# What is the best way to implement a recurrent task in ASP.NET WEBFORM - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, recurrence

In my web app, I can schedule exams by selecting date and can assign students and teachers to the test. So students and teachers are like resources for the exam. When creating each test, the corresponding test details will insert into the table with an auto_id (auto increment). And the resource details will store in another table by referring to this auto_id

```
exam_table
auto_id   nameofexam           starttime            endtime
1         EnglishRegular       12/07/22 04:00PM     12/07/22 05:00PM
2         SpanishRegular       12/07/22 02:00PM     12/07/22 03:00PM

exam_vs_resources_table
exam_auto_id      student              teacher       
1                  AAA                 TEACHER1       
1                  BBB                 NULL
1                  CCC                 NULL
2                  DDD                 TEACHER2
2                  AAA                 NULL       
2                  EEE                 NULL
```

Now, when creating an exam, user should have a choice to select if this exam need to repeat everyday/weekly/monthly. What is the best and easy way to achieve this? I am using GRIDVIEW to show all the details of exam. Grid view have provision to edit/delete the task details. This made me confuse how can I achieve the recurrent tasks in the current system.

Comment: You can achieve the same like the edit and delete buttons. You can add daily,weekly,monthly buttons or like a dropdown. And a textbox for the amount of times it should repeat. Than just loop the amount and add it to the database for the specific day which you can just calculate with DateTime object.

Comment: check for hangfire or quartz to perform recurrent task.